# Flatting analytics data - hit.type PAGE going missing

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to flatten analytics data in Bigquery and I've seen the other answers to unnest both hits and products however as soon as I include unnest(product) I get less results and only receiving the rows of hit.type = 'EVENT'.

If I comment out unnest(products) then I do receive more rows including 
hit.type = 'PAGE' and 
hit.type = 'EVENT' 
but then I cannot reference any product level data in the select because unnest(product) is commented out.

This only happens for a particular period of the data set, I am seeing PAGE hit types in earlier data. I don't get it! help!

What could be happening?

```
select 
h.type as hits_type
-- ,product.productSKU
--  ,product.v2ProductName as product_name

from  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`, 
unnest(hits) h, 
--unnest(h.product) as p
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem.

It needed a left join because I think there are hits that don't contain product records

```
from `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801` s, unnest(hits) h left join  unnest(h.product) p
```